# Get instance of Android system service(for example, AudioService)

Tags: android, service, system, aidl

I know that AudioManager provides API for AudioService. However, that I want is to get instance of AudioService class.

Studying the source showed that AudioManager makes a call to class in remote service.

I know that AudioManager have a field "sService", but is not an instance of AudioService, instead it is an instance of BinderInternal, IIRC. Can I somehow gain access to instance of AudioService? Or it is totally impossible because of security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you can easily get the reference to AudioService. I think you've just missed the appropriate part of the code:

```
private static IAudioService getService()
{
    if (sService != null) {
        return sService;
    }
    IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    sService = IAudioService.Stub.asInterface(b);
    return sService;
}
```

You can see that `sService` will be a reference to IAudioService. Similarly, in your application you can get direct reference to IAudioService. However, I do not understand why you may need to do this.

Comment: That's not what I want. IAudioService is just a Binder, and I don't need a Binder - I need an object of class AudioService: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/AudioService.java

Comment: The only possible way to interact with this service is through Binder because it is running in a separate process and only Binder is managed to marshal your calls to this service. So if you want to change a value in AudioService directly you cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks. That's just what I thought - I thought maybe somehow I can do it via some kind of trickery/exploit of native code, but it seems like it's impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately no, otherwise you'll be able to do anything in the system because System  Services are also working according to this model. You have access only to the methods which are defined in the AIDL interface.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's unfortunately :) Otherwise the security system would be nothing if anyone could access them in an easy way. Thank you.